# Best strategies for writing functional test for a node.js program that interacts with mysql database

Tags: node.js, docker, mocha.js, functional-testing

I have a node.js program which has interactions with a mysql server. Now I'm going to write a functional test using [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) for it.

The way I do the functional test is as the following:

1. Create a [mysql docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) with [dockerode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dockerode).
2. Let the node.js program connect to the mysql server docker container and write data to it.
3. Check if the database contains the expected data.
4. Remove the docker container.

The problems I have with the above strategy are:

1. How can I let node.js wait for the mysql container to be ready for connections? Currently, I use [setTimeout](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args) to wait for a few seconds. I don't think this is appropriate. Because different machines may require different amount of seconds for the container to be ready for connections.
2. Is it possible to create a fake mysql server instead of using docker container to create a real mysql server? I haven't found any node modules that mimic the behavior of a mysql server. Because I think that creating a fake mysql server allows me to know exactly when the server is ready for connections.

Does anyone have this kind of experience?

The following is part of my code:

```
let Docker = require('dockerode')
let docker = new Docker({socketPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'})

describe('Test AddShop2Database behavior', () => {
  before((done) => {
    setTimeout(setupDatabase, // setupDatabase create a mysql docker container
      1000, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(`setupDatabase error: ${err}`)
        } else {
          console.log(`setupDatabase data: ${data}`)
          done()
        }
      })
  })
  it('should add data to some tables', (done) => {
    done()
  })
  after(() => {
    // remove mysql docker container
    let container = docker.getContainer(ContainerName)
    container.remove({force: true}, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(`container remove error: ${err}`)
      } else {
        console.log(`container remove data: ${data}`)
      }
    })
  })
})
```